# Weird behavior in pread()?

Tags: c, linux, hard-drive

so I have a functions which takes a an offset and a width to read from a device(usually harddisks). Now I currently use fseeko() and fread() to read from the disk. However I like to replace this with pread as its just more concise. It seems however that pread ALWAYS reads from offset 0 no matter what.

Here is the code of the function:

Just some Heads up. 
I do have

```
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
```

at the top of my code. I also tried pread64() with the same result!

fseeko() with fread(), this does what I want!:

```
uint8_t retrievedata(FILE *fp,uint64_t seekpoint, uint64_t seekwidth) {
    unsigned char     buf[seekwidth];

    if(fseeko(fp,seekpoint,SEEK_SET)==0) {
        if(fread(buf,sizeof buf,1,fp)==1) {
             /* do work with retrieved data */
        }
        else {
            printf("ERROR READING AT: %"PRIu64"| WITH VAL WIDTH: %"PRIu64"\n",seekpoint,seekwidth);
            return 4;
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("ERROR SEEKING AT: %"PRIu64"\n",seekpoint);
        return 3;
    }
}
```

pread(), This always reads from offset 0 no matter what the 'seekpoint' is:

```
uint8_t retrievedata(FILE *fp,uint64_t seekpoint, uint64_t seekwidth) {
    unsigned char     buf[seekwidth]

    if (pread(fileno(fp),buf,seekwidth,seekpoint)!=-1) {
        /* do something */
    } else {
        printf("ERROR SEEKING AND/OR READING AT: %"PRIu64"\n",seekpoint);
        return 3;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not just the `PRIu64` macro messing with you?

Comment: no I checked actual data written to the file and see if it works, I made an empty file and wrote the very first byte with '11' and checked until it found it. turns out that it finds it everytime at the first byte even though 'seekpoint' is way out there. fseeko() with fread() does it correctly and only finds it at the beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enable compiler warnings (`-W -Wall` for GCC), and read the ["Feature Test Macro Requirements for GLIBC"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) sections in the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html).

The warnings would have indicated you missed another macro definition needed, and the [`man 2 pread`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) man page told you that the macro definition you also need is

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
```

to get the GNU C library version 2.12 or newer to declare `pread()` etc. correctly.

The behaviour you are seeing, is due to not having that declaration.

---

I want to tell you how I perceive the full story, because I hope it will show you exactly how and how much you can save sweat and effort by reading and understanding the [man pages](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/index.html), and more importantly, by **enabling and addressing the compiler warnings**.

I know you think you just don't have time to do all that right now (maybe later, right?), but you're wrong: it is one of the best ways to *save* time, when writing C for Linux (or POSIX-like systems in general).

I myself **always** use `-W -Wall` with GCC. It just makes it much easier to find where the cause of the problem lies. Right now, you were concentrating on the primary symptom instead, and since programming is not politics (yet), it won't get you anywhere.

So, full picture:

[`fread()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) returns the number of elements read. In your case, you read one element of `seekwidth` bytes, and you verify that one element was correctly read.

[`pread()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html) returns the number of bytes read. Your second code snippet tries to read `seekwidth` bytes starting at offset `seekpoint`, but you don't check how much data was actually read, you only check whether an error occurred.

Here is what I think is happening to you:

1. You have omitted the `#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L` declaration (prior to `#include <unistd.h>`) required since glibc 2.12 to get the `pread()` function prototype declared
2. You are compiling without warnings, or you are ignoring the *"implicit declaration of function `pread`"* warning
3. You are compiling on a 32-bit architecture, or to 32-bit architecture using `-m32` GCC option

Without a function prototype, the compiler assumes all parameters to the `pread()` function are ints -- and therefore 32-bit --, and only supplies a 32-bit *`seekpoint`* value to `pread()`. The three first parameters (an int, a pointer, and a size_t) all happen to be 32-bit, but the fourth parameter, file offset, is 64-bit. (Remember, you told your C library so, using `#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64`.)

This means that the 64-bit file offset `pread()` receives, is garbage. (It depends on the byte order -- little-endian or Intel-like, or big-endian or Motorola/PowerPC/ARM-like -- and how the particular architecture binary interface (ABI) passes the fourth parameter to a function, exactly *how* the value is garbled.)

In this case, I believe you're targeting 32-bit Intel architecture, where often the value `pread()` actually receives (as garbled) is positive and larger than the file size, and therefore `pread()` returns 0: *"past end-of-file, no more data to read"*.

Your code ignores that (since it is not -1), and instead assumes it read the data successfully. Most likely the data you're seeing is from a previous read -- `pread()` does not modify the buffer if it returns 0.

(There are other possible variants of the situation, too; perhaps even some where `pread()` always receives a zero as the (garbled) offset. It does not actually matter, as in all cases having the proper function prototype fixes the problem. You do need to check the `pread()` return value, too, as there are no guarantees it'll actually read the number of bytes you requested. It does so often, yes; but there are no guarantees, so make no unfounded assumptions, please.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the thorough explanation! I Had seen -W -wall before but never knew what it meant. is it some kind of extended compiling warning because I never got a normal warning or error. you were right that I did no have the the right definition at the top and also am compiling on 32bit. I shall fix my code and report back later. Again thank you